# excel vba error missing right parenthesis

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA - Not sure why I am getting the right parenthesis error when trying to run the below query

```
Select 
count(distinct(assg_nbr)) as ASG_CNT
, sum(sel_qty) as "Total Cases"
, trunc(assg_end_date) as "assg_end_date"
,count(distinct(empl_id)) as SEL_CNT
, case when to_char(assg_end_date, 'D') < 7 then to_char(assg_end_date + (7 - to_char(assg_end_date, 'D')), 'DD-MON-YY') else to_char(assg_end_date, 'DD-MON-YY') end as "W/E DATE"
, upper(to_char(assg_end_date, 'dy')) as "Day"
, concat(to_char(assg_end_date, 'hh24'), '00') as "COM_HR"
, whse_type
From
--table
where org_code = '13'
--and resel_assg_flg = 'Y'
and assg_end_date between current_Date - 7*5 and current_Date - 7*0
and whse_item_nbr <> '0' and whse_item_nbr is not null
group by trunc(assg_end_date)
, case when to_char(assg_end_date, 'D') < 7 then to_char(assg_end_date + (7 - to_char(assg_end_date, 'D')), 'DD-MON-YY') else to_char(assg_end_date, 'DD-MON-YY') end
, upper(to_char(assg_end_date, 'dy'))
, concat(to_char(assg_end_date, 'hh24'), '00')
, whse_type
```

need this to run through VBA

Comment: On the first glance, the SQL statement looks okay. The question is how you write it in the VBA editor - I assume you have invalid quotes. For example, when you need a quote character in a string, you have to double it so that the VBA compiler knows that this is not meant as end of string character. My advice: Write the SQL string into a variable and check that with the debugger.

Comment: Sub Update()
   Dim LastRowSelectorData As Long
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim SQL As String
        LastRowPick = Worksheets("SelectorData").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("SelectorData").Range("A2:H" & LastRowPick).ClearContents

Comment: Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
        cn.Open ( _
        "User ID=John" & _
        ";Password=Smith" & _
        ";Data Source=tble" & _
        ";Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle")
           SQL = Worksheets("SelectorData").Range("K10").Value
 rs.CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
        rs.Open (SQL), cn
      Worksheets("SelectorData").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
   Set rs = Nothing Set cn = Nothing
End Sub

Comment: Please put updates of your code in your question, not in the comments. You can't format it in the comments and is therefor harder to read + it's clearer for future readers what your question is (fully) about.

Comment: So you have your SQL statement in Cell K10?

Comment: Yes that is where it is in K10

Comment: Try running that SQL in your database's query tool and it may tell you where the problem is.

Comment: the query runs fine in oracle

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT(assg_nbr)) as ASG_CNT

It should be:
COUNT(DISTINCT assg_nbr) as ASG_CNT
```